# How to fix/change Inkscape scale factor while exporting into SVG?

Tags: inkscape, svg, export, scale

I printed a PDF drawing with Chromium. This is my reference physical output.

I imported the PDF into Inkscape (0.92.3), cloned the drawing and then printed within Inkscape. The output has the correct dimensions.

When I export the same drawing into SVG, open it with Chromium and print, it is printed slightly scaled down (exactly 0.90 times).

When I open the SVG and change the line from

```
<svg
    ...
    transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,1122.6667)"><g
...
```

to

```
<svg
    ...
    transform="matrix(1.48144444,0,0,-1.48144444,0,1122.6667)"><g
...
```

(where `1.48144444 is 1.333333 / 0.90`), resulting SVG is printed with the correct dimensions via Chromium.

Since `0.90` is not equal to `90px_per_mm / 96px_per_mm`, it doesn't seem to be a misconfigured printing parameter. What could be the problem? How can I enter the `0.90` scale factor to somewhere for once to be able to export to SVG correctly everytime?

Comment: Can you share your example files? It will make it easier to find out what is happening.

Comment: Sure. The [pdf is here](https://github.com/aktos-io/aecad/files/2846569/test.pdf) and [the resulting SVG is here](https://github.com/aktos-io/aecad/files/2846567/test-tiled.svg.txt). The correct outer diameter should be 18.50 mm.

Comment: Then it's already wrong in Inkscape - I get 18.7 mm? I don't see anything suspicious in the file. Could Chromium use different printer margins for printing?

Comment: 18.7mm including or excluding the trace width? I suppose you included the trace with. Okay, the problem is found: I changed the "Margins"  setting in the Chromium print options from "Default" to "None" and the printed output dimensions are exactly as expected. I guess there must be some attributes required in the SVG in order to prevent the printed result from being affected by the margin settings.

Comment: Nope, that's a printer setting. Something like 'fit to page' or so...

Comment: Correct, it's printer settings that are configured within Chromium. I'm looking forward to achieve a solution where we could "offer" printer settings within the SVG with some attributes.

Comment: I don't think that's ever going to happen ...

Comment: Yes, [it seems so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633977/1952991). Maybe a custom server could be written to handle some custom printer settings attribute of the SVG.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer if you'd like to add it as an answer.